# How to write info in console window on the position

Tags: c#

I'm working with VS2015 and C# on a console application in which I'm logging info for the end-user while the application is running.

In one situation I want to show the user per example that items of a list are handled.

So I want to write an info like "Item 1 of 100 is handled".

With `Console.WriteLine` I would get a lot of lines which are standing under each other.

Do I have a chance to write the info in the same line at the same place?

What I mean is, I want to write a new line with "Item 1 of 100" and then writing at the same line and place "2 of 100", "3 of 100" and so on.

Comment: The old easy way was: Print a new line, Print the first "Text". When update is needed, send a brunch of `\b` or a `\r`, print the new line. This is error free from async worker trying the get position -1 and end out of bound

Comment: care full with Cursor postion if you handle those item in parralel.

Comment: @DragandDrop - Thanks, I was not aware of that. Flagged it.